# If $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, to what correspond the product measure induced by $X$ and $Y$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space. I know that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $(X,Y)$ induce a measure on $\mathbb R^2$ if and only if they are independent. The measure is given by $$\nu(A\times B)=\mathbb P\{(X,Y)\in A\times B\}=\mathbb P\{X\in A\}\mathbb P\{Y\in B\}.$$

Now, if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, for sure $$\mu(A\times B)=\iint_{A\times B}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx$$
where $f_{X,Y}$ is the joint density is a measure on $\mathbb R^2$. Using this definition, they don't need to be independent. So why if they are not independent, they don't induce a measure on $\mathbb R^2$ since $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathbb R^2$ ?

Answer (score 2):

It's indeed a measure on $\mathbb R^2$, but it's not a product measure since product measure must satisfies $$(\mu\otimes\nu)(A\times B)=\mu(A)\nu(B).$$

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you. (+1)

Comment: Maybe you can answer this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3223489/what-is-mathbb-ex-in-mathbb-ex-y-mathbb-ex-mathbb-ey) ?