# What is $\mathbb E[X]$ in $\mathbb E[(X,Y)]=(\mathbb E[X],\mathbb E[Y])$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I just ask a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3223449/if-x-and-y-are-not-independent-to-what-correspond-the-product-measure-induc). I know now that if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, then $$\mu(A\times B)=\int_A\int_B f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx$$
is a measure on $\mathbb R^2$ (but not the production measure). Now, we define $$\mathbb E[(X,Y)]:=(\mathbb E[X],\mathbb E[Y]).$$

But what is $\mathbb E[X]$ ? Is it $$\iint_{\mathbb R^2} x f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy \quad \text{or}\quad \int_{\mathbb R} xf_X(x)dx \ \ ?$$
where $f_{X}$ is the density of $X$ and $f_{X,Y}$ the density of $(X,Y)$. I know that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, both integral are the same, but what happen if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent ?

Comment: Both are the same. the marginal PDF can be obtained from the joint PDF by $$f_X(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y,$$ hence the equality of two integrals in question follows from Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space. As always,

$$\mathbb E[X]=\int_\Omega X\,\mathrm d \mathbb P.$$
Now, if $\nu(A):=\mathbb P\{X\in A\}$ is absolutely continuous wrt to Lebesgue measure, then indeed  $$\int_\Omega  X\,\mathrm d \mathbb P=\int_{\mathbb R}xf_X(x)\,\mathrm d x,$$
for some $f_X$. But, remember that $$f_X(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d y.$$

So at the end, both are the same.

Comment: Great @Surb, thank for your answer :) That's very helpful.